# trying to make two div blocks sit next to each other and fill page

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/UeLMA/1/

The HTML:

```
<div id="left" style="background: red; display: inline-block; float: left">
    aaaa<br />
    aaaaa
</div>
<div id="right" style="background: yellow; float: left"></div>
```

I want #right to fill the rest of the screen that #left isn't using. To achieve this I'm using jquery:

```
$('#left').height($(window).height());
$('#right').height($(window).height());
$('#right').width($(window).width() - $('#left').outerWidth());
```

Only problem: it isn't working. Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UeLMA/1/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working version:** http://jsfiddle.net/UeLMA/4/

add this reset to your CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The two divs you have don't take up the entire window, so the second div is getting a width that doesn't fit next to the first one. Change the second width to `$('#right').parent().width() - $('#left').outerWidth()` and it works.

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UeLMA/5/

What I'm doing is using the `.parent()` selector instead of the window to make sure that the thing I'm sizing the divs for is what they're actually fitting into. I believe that they fit into a `body` element that has some margin or padding setting it off from the window.

Comment: Of course, if you resize the window, the widths don't get updated and the effect breaks.  Is it worth adding an action that checks for window resizing?

Comment: There's a number of ways you could get around it, one of which would be to add a resize event. If jQuery is already being used, adding a resize event would be pretty easy, so it might be the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to achieve this.  Just a few basic CSS principles.

1. To achieve 100% height, ALL parents of the element you want 100% in height must also be set at 100% height.

   **CSS:** `html, body, #left, #right { height: 100%; margin:0; }`
2. To fill the page width, just float both block elements to the left and set their width to `50%` (or a different ratio equaling 100%)

   **CSS:** `#left, #right { float: left; width: 50%; }`

You can see the working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/UeLMA/2/

Comment: I'm doing `display: inline-block` so that #left is only as big as the text inside it. I don't want it to be a fixed percent. The `height: 100%` bit is cool but per what I just said I think I still need jquery to do the width? See http://jsfiddle.net/ktz52/ . I tried `width: 100%` on #right as well to no avail.

Comment: You don't need scripting for the variable width if you only float the left part.
http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/YcC3C/

Answer (score 1):

You have to account for the padding and margin around the body.

http://jsfiddle.net/UeLMA/6/

CSS:

```
#left { background: red; display: inline-block; float: left }
#right { background: yellow; float: left; }
body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

And change `outerWidth()` to `width()`:

```
$('#left').width()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use JQuery. The main problem in your code is div takes 100% width as default so the right div comes below so just give width to both left and right div as needed, add height:100%; to each of them and remove Jquery code